# Best realistic-case scenario, what does our climate look like in 30 years...50 years...a 100 years?

Tags: climate-change

Let's assume, humanity can decide to care more about the survival of our species, our duty to our descendants, than getting rich now. How long would it reasonably take to get to net-zero carbon emissions? How much longer with the planet continue to heat? Looking ahead 30, 50, or 100 years, what will the climate be in this best realistic-case scenario?

Comment: If we didn't tip any scales (permafrost, seafloor methane) which would release more GHG, the temperature rise would flatten and maybe even reverse.